# WinRT ObservableCollection.RemoveAt() results in COMExcetion HRESULT E_FAIL

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have an ObservableCollection that a ListBox is databound to. I can add items to the ObservableCollection without issue, and the UI updates, but if I try to call either Remove or RemoveAt to allow the user to delete entries I end up with this:

> '10Done.WindowsPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was
>   built without symbols. A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll An exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a
>   COM component.

Can I not remove items from a collection that is databound?

Comment: It would be remarkable if any API had a general restriction in that it allows only adding elements to a collection, but not removal. You should post a good code example, showing exactly what you're doing, with the _minimum_ code needed to do so. Explain exactly where the exception occurs and what the stack trace is. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve